# First date of current Fiscal Year

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to get the First Date of the current Fiscal year. In my case the Fiscal year starts in Oct.

Example: I need the 10/01/2015

I would generally use the below query to the get the first day of the current year but how do I change it to get the first date of fiscal year?

```
select 
    convert(varchar(12), (
      DateAdd(month, (
        Month(getdate()) - 1) * -1, 
        DateAdd(Day, (
          Day(getdate()) - 1) * -1, 
          getdate()))),
    103) as StartYear
```

Comment: You know current year and a month to start a fiscal year, why do you need a query then?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply following logic: Subtract 9 months from the current date, find Jan 1st of this year and add 9 months again:

```
DATEADD(MONTH, 9, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, DATEADD(MONTH, -9, GETDATE())), 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. At first Subtract 9 months from current date to get the previous year(your Fasical year).
2. Then take the year difference with 0 to your date.
3. Now add the year difference with 0 to get the starting of a month.
4. Finally you need to add the 9 months to get the starting month of a Fasical Year.
5. As year example the require format "10/01/2015". So get that you can use convert function with 101.

   ```
   select convert(varchar(12), DATEADD(MONTH, 9, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, DATEADD(MONTH, -9, GETDATE())), 0)), 101) as StartYear
   ```

Comment: Can you edit your proposed answer to expand on what this does and how it addresses the OP?

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @fiscal     date    = '2015-10-01'

; with dates
as
(
    select  date = '2015-09-30' union all
    select  date = '2015-10-01' union all
    select  date = '2016-09-30' union all
    select  date = '2016-10-01'
)
select  *,
    fiscal  = case  when date < dateadd(year, year(date) - year(@fiscal), @fiscal)
            then dateadd(year, year(date) - year(@fiscal) - 1, @fiscal)
            else dateadd(year, year(date) - year(@fiscal), @fiscal)
            end
from    dates

/* result
date       fiscal
---------- ----------
2015-09-30 2014-10-01
2015-10-01 2015-10-01
2016-09-30 2015-10-01
2016-10-01 2016-10-01
*/
```